# Debugging a hard fault in ARM Cortex-M4

Tags: debugging, arm

I am at my wit's end trying to debug a hard fault on an EFR32BG12 processor. I've been following the instructions in the Silicon Labs knowledge base here:

https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/32-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2014/05/26/debug_a_hardfault-78gc

I've also been using the Keil app note here to fill in some details:

http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf

I've managed to get the hard fault to occur quite consistently in one place. When the hard fault occurs, the code from the knowledge base article gives me the following values (pushed onto the stack by the processor before calling the hard fault handler):

```
Name     Type        Value               Location
~~~~     ~~~~        ~~~~~               ~~~~~~~~
cfsr     uint32_t    0x20000 (Hex)       0x2000078c    
hfsr     uint32_t    0x40000000 (Hex)    0x20000788    
mmfar    uint32_t    0xe000ed34 (Hex)    0x20000784    
bfar     uint32_t    0xe000ed38 (Hex)    0x20000780    
r0       uint32_t    0x0 (Hex)           0x2000077c    
r1       uint32_t    0x8 (Hex)           0x20000778    
r2       uint32_t    0x0 (Hex)           0x20000774    
r3       uint32_t    0x0 (Hex)           0x20000770    
r12      uint32_t    0x1 (Hex)           0x2000076c    
lr       uint32_t    0xab61 (Hex)        0x20000768    
pc       uint32_t    0x38dc8 (Hex)       0x20000764    
psr      uint32_t    0x0 (Hex)           0x20000760
```

Looking at the Keil app note, I believe a CFSR value of 0x20000 indicates a Usage Fault with the INVSTATE bit set, i.e.:

> INVSTATE: Invalid state: 0 = no invalid state 1 = the processor has
>   attempted to execute an instruction that makes illegal use of the
>   Execution Program Status Register (EPSR). When this bit is set, the PC
>   value stacked for the exception return points to the instruction that
>   attempted the illegal use of the EPSR. Potential reasons: a) Loading a
>   branch target address to PC with LSB=0. b) Stacked PSR corrupted
>   during exception or interrupt handling. c) Vector table contains a
>   vector address with LSB=0.

The PC value pushed onto the stack by the exception (provided by the code from the knowledge base article) seems to be 0x38dc8. If I go to this address in the Simplicity Studio "Disassembly" window, I see the following:

```
00038db8:   str     r5,[r5,#0x14]
00038dba:   str     r0,[r7,r1]
00038dbc:   str     r4,[r5,#0x14]
00038dbe:   ldr     r4,[pc,#0x1e4] ; 0x38fa0
00038dc0:   strb    r1,[r4,#0x11]
00038dc2:   ldr     r5,[r4,#0x64]
00038dc4:   ldrb    r3,[r4,#0x5]
00038dc6:   movs    r3,r6
00038dc8:   strb    r1,[r4,#0x15]
00038dca:   ldr     r4,[r4,#0x14]
00038dcc:   cmp     r7,#0x6f
00038dce:   cmp     r6,#0x30
00038dd0:   str     r7,[r6,#0x14]
00038dd2:   lsls    r6,r6,#1
00038dd4:   movs    r5,r0
00038dd6:   movs    r0,r0
```

The address appears to be well past the end of my code. If I look at the same address in the "Memory" window, this is what I see:

```
0x00038DC8  69647561 2E302F6F 00766177 00000005  audio/0.wav.....
0x00038DD8  00000000 000F4240 00000105 00000000  ....@B..........
0x00038DE8  00000000 00000000 00000005 00000000  ................
0x00038DF8  0001C200 00000500 00001000 00000000  .Â..............
0x00038E08  00000000 F00000F0 02F00001 0003F000  ....ð..ð..ð..ð..
0x00038E18  F00004F0 06010005 01020101 01011201  ð..ð............
0x00038E28  35010121 01010D01 6C363025 2E6E6775  !..5....%06lugn.
0x00038E38  00746164 00000001 000008D0 00038400  dat.....Ð.......
```

Curiously, "audio/0.wav" is a static string which is part of the firmware. If I understand correctly, what I've learned here is that PC somehow gets set to this point in memory, which of course is not a valid instruction and causes the hard fault.

To debug the issue, I need to know how PC came to be set to this incorrect value. I believe the LR register should give me an idea. The LR register pushed onto the stack by the exception seems to be 0xab61. If I look at this location, I see the following in the Disassembly window:

```
1270            dp->sect = clst2sect(fs, clst);
0000ab58:   ldr     r0,[r7,#0x10]
0000ab5a:   ldr     r1,[r7,#0x14]
0000ab5c:   bl      0x00009904
0000ab60:   mov     r2,r0
0000ab62:   ldr     r3,[r7,#0x4]
0000ab64:   str     r2,[r3,#0x18]
```

It looks to me like the problem occurs during this call specifically:

```
0000ab5c:   bl      0x00009904
```

This makes me think that the problem occurs as a result of a corrupt stack, which causes clst2sect to return to an invalid part of memory rather than to 0xab60. The code for clst2sect is pretty innocuous:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Get physical sector number from cluster number                        */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

DWORD clst2sect (   /* !=0:Sector number, 0:Failed (invalid cluster#) */
    FATFS* fs,      /* Filesystem object */
    DWORD clst      /* Cluster# to be converted */
)
{
    clst -= 2;      /* Cluster number is origin from 2 */
    if (clst >= fs->n_fatent - 2) return 0;     /* Is it invalid cluster number? */
    return fs->database + fs->csize * clst;     /* Start sector number of the cluster */
}
```

Does this analysis sound about right?

I suppose the problem I've run into is that I have no idea what might cause this kind of behaviour... I've tried putting breakpoints in all of my interrupt handlers, to see if one of them might be corrupting the stack, but there doesn't seem to be any pattern--sometimes, no interrupt handler is called but the problem still occurs.

In that case, though, it's hard for me to see how a program might try to execute code at a location well past the actual end of the code... I feel like a function pointer might be a likely candidate, but in that case I would expect to see the problem show up, e.g., where a function pointer is used. However, I don't see any function pointers used near where the error is occurring.

Perhaps there is more information I can extract from the debug information I've given above? The problem is quite reproducible, so if there's something I have not tried, but which you think might give some insight, I would love to hear it.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Could you give a bit more context?  Is this bare metal, or is there an OS?

Comment: The error is between 0x0000ab5c, and the next BL, somewhere where there is a PC modifying instruction. It seems your stack is OK here, are there any hints above/below this stack location?

Comment: @cooperised This is bare metal with a simple cooperative scheduler.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane The code at 0xab5c is inside a function called dir_sdi. It looks like there are no further bl instructions between this location and the end of the function. Would the return from dir_sdi count as a PC modifying instruction, or could the error be somewhere past that?

Comment: this return is presumably a pop to the PC? It could be past that, until you find something that modifies the LR, and it could be that return which is taking a corrupted value.

Comment: As you say, the LR value is pushed to the stack at the start of dir_sdi and then popped to PC to return. If I understand correctly, the last time LR is set is when dir_sdi is called, which means the error must occur somewhere between that point and the next time LR is set. This *could* be happening on return from dir_sdi, but could also happen later (but still before the next bl or blx call). What sorts of things (other than pop to PC) might set PC to the invalid value? Is it possible to add a breakpoint, e.g., if PC is ever set to 0x38dc8?

Comment: I found a way to add a breakpoint at 0x38dc8, but it appears the exception is called before the breakpoint halts execution--the breakpoint never gets triggered.

Comment: Bare metal with a simple cooperative scheduler... so does that mean that there's a full context switch and tasks have individual stacks, or do they nest and share a single stack?

Comment: @cooperised I think it's more basic than you're imagining. I have a main loop which keeps track of the last time each task was run. On each loop, the task's timer, desired period and priority are used to calculate it's dynamic priority. The task with highest dynamic priority is selected and its associated task function is called. When that function returns, the loop continues and another task is selected etc.

Comment: @cooperised My scheduler is very similar to this one: https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/blob/master/src/main/scheduler/scheduler.c

Comment: The problems arose when I converted the f_write function in FatFS to a state machine. This was done so that the function did not need to block while waiting for the microSD card to finish an operation. The state machine is "pumped" by its own task function and no other FatFS calls are allowed while the state machine is in operation. I can see the potential for some bugs here, but it's not clear to me how it would cause the hard fault, since, e.g., there are no interrupts involved.

Comment: And for what it's worth, after three weeks of trying to figure out the hard fault, I'm currently rewriting the f_write state machine in the hopes that this will eliminate the error. I'm not keen on this debugging method, since it doesn't guarantee I've found the cause of the problem. I'd rather use the tools available to me to identify the cause directly. However, three weeks of using those tools without results is taking a toll on my sanity, so I thought I'd try something new in parallel with consulting you guys.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  So the 'tasks' actually run to completion, correct?  They can not yield mid-way and resume later, and the whole system therefore uses a single stack?  The reason I ask is that around 80% of the time when I've seen bugs like this they've been caused by cross-stack corruption when task stacks are not large enough and stack overflow occurs.  If there's only one stack, this is not an option.

Comment: Btw on the assumption that there's only one stack, can I assume you've checked to make sure it's big enough and isn't overflowing?

Comment: @cooperised Yes, each task runs to completion before it returns. Regarding stack size, is there a way I can check directly how much stack is actually being used? I tried doubling the stack size from 0x800 to 0x1000, but the problem remains.

Comment: If you've tried doubling the stack size and it hasn't helped then this *probably* isn't the problem.  The most reliable way to check for an overflowing stack is to configure the MPU to make a small region at the bottom of the allocated stack space inaccessible; an overflowing stack will then trigger a data abort exception and you can work back from there.  An easier but less reliable method is to try and work out where your stack usage is greatest and put a breakpoint in so you can peek `r13`.

Comment: The point of maximum stack use might well be coincident with the point at which you have the most nested function calls, but large non-static local arrays are also often responsible for using large amounts of stack space.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After about a month of chasing this one, I managed to identify the cause of the problem. I hope I can give enough information here that this will be useful to someone else.

In the end, the problem was caused by passing a pointer to a non-static local variable to a state machine which changed the value at that memory location later on. Because the local variable was no longer in scope, that memory location was a random point in the stack, and changing the value there corrupted the stack.

The problem was difficult to track down for two reasons:

1. Depending on how the code compiled, the changed memory location could be something non-critical like another local variable, which would cause a much more subtle error. Only when I got lucky would the change affect the PC register and cause a hard fault.
2. Even when I found a version of the code that consistently generated a hard fault, the actual hard fault typically occurred somewhere up the call stack, when a function returned and popped the stack value into PC. This made it difficult to identify the cause of the problem--all I knew was that *something* was corrupting the stack before that function return.

A few tools were really helpful in identifying the cause of the problem:

1. Early on, I had identified a block of code where the hard fault usually occurred using GPIO pins. I would toggle a pin high before entering the block and low when exiting the block. Then I performed many tests, checking if the pin was high or low when the hard fault occurred, and used a sort of binary search to determine the smallest block of code which consistently contained all the hard faults.
2. The hard fault pushes a number of important registers onto the stack. These helped me confirm where the PC register was becoming corrupt, and also helped me understand that it was becoming corrupt as a result of a stack corruption.
3. Starting somewhere before that block of code and stepping forward while keeping an eye on local variables, I was able to identify a function call that was corrupting the stack. I could confirm this using Simplicity Studio's memory view.
4. Finally, stepping through the offending function in detail, I realized that the problem was occurring when I dereferenced a stored pointer and wrote to that memory location. Looking back at where that pointer value was set, I realized it had been set to point to a non-static local variable that was now out of scope.

Thanks to @SeanHoulihane and @cooperised, who helped me eliminate a few possible causes and gave me a little more confidence with the debugging tools.

Comment: Kind of late to mention it now, but ETM trace would be the 'ideal' tool to use to debug this. Unfortunately, tools are not super cheap, unless you can run at about 20 MHz.

Comment: That does look interesting. I'm running at 38.4 MHz, but could probably step that down for some debugging purposes. Is there a specific tool I should look into?

Comment: https://github.com/orbcode/orbuculum for the open source tools and FPGA low speed capture. ULink-Pro if time is money. I believe the eval Keil version supports trace, but I've never actually used trace outside simulation...